# Okhttp java 11 exceptions

Tags: java, okhttp, java-11

We've migrated to java 11 and started to see from time to time very strange request failures with the exceptions on our **test** environment(it's docker container deployed to kubernetes):

okhttp version 3.12.1:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$EmptyList.get(Collections.java:4481)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:326)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:283)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:168)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:92)
    at org.springframework.http.client.OkHttp3ClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(OkHttp3ClientHttpRequest.java:73)
```

okhttp version 3.14.2:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname graph.facebook.com not verified (no certificates)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:353)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:300)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:185)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:224)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:108)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:221)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
    at org.springframework.http.client.OkHttp3ClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(OkHttp3ClientHttpRequest.java:73)
```

We just use Spring's OkHttp3ClientHttpRequestFactory with next OkHttpClient config

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .readTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();
```

Unfortunately I can't reproduce it on my local machine.

Are there any known issues of okhttp with java 11 and SSL?

Comment: Is it working in lower version of java like java 8 and 9 ?

Comment: @sambit `We've migrated to java 11 and started to see from time to time very strange request` ...

Comment: Have you tested this code in prior to Java 11, I mean have you tested in Java 8 or 9 version ?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly fine with java 8

Comment: It says "javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname graph.facebook.com not verified (no certificates)", it means it requires some certificate. Did you use any certificate file which remains inside java/jre/lib/security folder ? If you use that, hopefully it will solve your problem.

Comment: No it is packaged into docker image. And if your assumption is correct why that happens from time to time? some requests works perfectly and we have only one instance of the container

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug in Java 11. OkHttp’s tracking bug is [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4703).

You can workaround by upgrading to Java 11.0.2, turning off TLSv1.3, or by switching to Conscrypt.

Comment: It has been reproduced on OpenJDK 11.0.2.
With tls 1.2 need to test more but first impression is that it works fine as well